# How can I access S3 Bucket from within ECS Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

I'm currently debugging an ECS Task which basically grabs a message from a SQS queue, downloads a file from S3, manipulates it and uploads it back to S3. This script works fine locally and if I run it in a docker container it also works fine locally. When I create a task in ECS with the docker image and let it run it doesn't seem to process the file. In order to find the problem I created a very small script which simply uploads a file to s3

```
aws s3 cp hello-world.txt s3://my-buckt-name/hello-world.txt
```

This again works fine locally, and it works fine in a docker container (locally). When I create a task for it, it simply won't work. The ECS Task has a role that has "Full S3 Access"... any ideas?

Could it be that I need a bucket policy on my s3 bucket? I thought it would be sufficient if I grant access to the AWS services that need it, but apparently it's not working... and using my admin account I can use the awscli to do create objects in my bucket...

EDIT
Ok, it seems that the problem is the region. I created another bucket in a different region (it was Frankfurt before and now Ireland) and now I can copy and paste to the bucket as I would expect. Funnily I can create buckets programmatically (even from within my ECS task) but I can't seem the create objects in the buckets that are located in Frankfurt.

Comment: How exactly is it failing? Timeout? Access denied?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure tbh. The container stops with the hint that "Essential container in task exited", which is ok I suppos, because the container just runs the script and that's it. But no file appears in my bucket. It has to do something with IAM, I'm just clueless as to what. The ECS task has a role with full S3 access. Shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: Full S3 access is dangerous btw.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's just for debugging Poseures, thanks :)

Comment: @kidman01 What programming language are you making the S3 requests to the different region in?  I can provide an example of how to do this.

Comment: I'm using a simple shell script for this purpose. As I edited above: The script works with Region "us-east-1" and "eu-west-1" but for some reason not with "eu-central-1". Anything else equal. So my testing container was a simple Ubuntu container, containing a test file, my test script and the aws cli. The script would simply copy the test file to my s3 bucket. No matter whether I created the bucket via the cli (from my machine) oder via the management console, Frankfurt (eu-central-1) did not work. Another bucket in Ireland with the same settings and it worked. Strange!